# Serializing the state of several form elements as JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have code as below

```
var reported_psdArray = [];
$("select[name=reported_psd]").each(function() {
  var item = {
    "id": $(this).attr('id'),
    "value": $(this).val(),
    "text": $("option:selected", this).text()
  };
  reported_psdArray.push(item);
})
reported_psd = JSON.stringify({
  reported_psd: reported_psdArray
});

var more_infoArray = [];
$("textarea[name=more_info]").each(function() {
  var item = {
    "id": $(this).attr('id'),
    "value": $(this).val()
  };
  more_infoArray.push(item);
})
more_info = JSON.stringify({
  more_info: more_infoArray
});

var auth_managerArray = [];
$("input[name=auth_manager]").each(function() {
  var item = {
    "id": $(this).attr('id'),
    "value": $(this).val()
  };
  auth_managerArray.push(item);
})
auth_manager = JSON.stringify({
  auth_manager: auth_managerArray
});

return "[" + reported_psd + "," + more_info + "," + auth_manager + "]
```

Now, this works fine. For small forms, it's just copying/pasting a few times. My question is how I'd make this work for hundreds of inputs? For select items I would need the value of the actual text - I would not need these for the others.

Corresponding HTML would be a series of HTML elements such as:

```
<input type="text" name="auth_manager">
<textarea name="more_info"></textarea>
```

Sometimes there may be multiple elements of the same name

Server side technology is PHP.

Comment: Have you tried with hundreds of elements? Is there an issue?

Comment: Yes, copying/pasting/writing it all!

Comment: Do you mean having hundreds of different names?

Comment: Yes - If my form had dozens and dozens of fields, all different names, then this task of code will be time consuming and take up many many lines.

Comment: Why can't you use `serialize()` for all of this. Have created huge forms in the past and used serialize on them with no issues. Then everything is in `_POST` as array

Comment: If you had two with the same name, it only pick up the last input

Comment: various ways to handle that if create form properly such as using `[]` names

Answer (score 1):

Looks as though there is some repetitive code.  Consider refactoring to a DRY function that accepts the DOM node type and the name attribute as arguments.

```
function stringifyFormElementValues(formInputType, name) {
    var selectorString = formInputType + "[name=" + name + "]";
    var matches = [];
    $(selectorString).each(function() {
        var item = {};
        item.id = $(this).attr('id');
        item.value = $(this).val();
        if (formInputType === "select") {
            item.text = $("option:selected", this).text();
        }
        matches.push(item);
    });
    var result = {};
    result[name] = matches;

    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

You can then call this based on the elements and names you care about, and do whatever you need to (build up your array, for example).  Or if you aren't picky about what goes in there you can select all of your form inputs, `.each()` over them and call the method on each matched element to build up a comprehensive array.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have all the basic functions for `select`, `textarea` and `input`... Now you want to use those on many possible elements names.

So here is how to loop throught all names, for each element type.

That is just a loop added on each... To grab all different names, then use your function with the collected names.

```
function serialise_all(){

  // Selects
  var select_names = [];
  $(document).find("select").each(function(){
    var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
    if(select_names.indexof(thisName) == -1){
      select_names.push($(this).attr("name"));
    }
  });

  var reported_psdArray = [];
  for (i=0;i<select_names.length;i++){
    $("select[name="+select_names[i]+"]").each(function() {
      var item = {
        "id": $(this).attr('id'),
        "value": $(this).val(),
        "text": $("option:selected", this).text()
      };
      reported_psdArray.push(item);
    })
  }
  reported_psd = JSON.stringify({
    reported_psd: reported_psdArray
  });

  // Textareas
  var textarea_names = [];
  $(document).find("textarea").each(function(){
    var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
    if(textarea_names.indexof(thisName) == -1){
      textarea_names.push($(this).attr("name"));
    }
  });

  var more_infoArray = [];
  for (i=0;i<textarea_names.length;i++){
    $("textarea[name="+textarea_names[i]+"]").each(function() {
      var item = {
        "id": $(this).attr('id'),
        "value": $(this).val()
      };
      more_infoArray.push(item);
    })
  }
  more_info = JSON.stringify({
    more_info: more_infoArray
  });

  // Inputs
  var input_names = [];
  $(document).find("input").each(function(){
    var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
    if(input_names.indexof(thisName) == -1){
      input_names.push($(this).attr("name"));
    }
  });

  var auth_managerArray = [];
  for (i=0;i<input_names.length;i++){
    $("input[name="+input_names[i]+"]").each(function() {
      var item = {
        "id": $(this).attr('id'),
        "value": $(this).val()
      };
      auth_managerArray.push(item);
    })
  }
  auth_manager = JSON.stringify({
    auth_manager: auth_managerArray
  });

  return "[" + reported_psd + "," + more_info + "," + auth_manager + "];
}
```